# I am getting date related error in my project with spring boot angular

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, date, datetime

`Repository`

```
            "AND s.date BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate")
    List<Spending> getSpendingByMonthAndDateRange(@Param("monthNumber") int monthNumber,
                                                  @Param("startDate") Date startDate,
                                                  @Param("endDate") Date endDate);
```

`Service`

```
 @Override
    public List<Spending> getSpendingByMonth(String month) {
        int monthNumber = getMonthNumber(month);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthNumber - 1);
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        Date startDate = calendar.getTime();

        calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
        calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1);
        Date endDate = calendar.getTime();

        return spendingRepository.getSpendingByMonthAndDateRange(monthNumber, startDate, endDate);
    }


    private int getMonthNumber(String month) {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM");
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        try {
            calendar.setTime(dateFormat.parse(month));
            return calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid month format");
        }
    }
```

`Controller`

```
    @GetMapping("/spendings/{month}")
    public List<Spending> getSpendingByMonth(@PathVariable("month") String month) {
        return spendingService.getSpendingByMonth(month);
    }
```

`When I post this spring boot method postmande this request http://localhost:8081/api/spendings/Haz or http://localhost:8081/api/spendings/Haziran like this, all the expenses in the entered month value come. I want to use the month value in Turkish in api`

`Spending Service ts`

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SpendingService {

  private baseUrl = 'http://localhost:8081/api/';
  

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getAllSpendings(): Observable<Spending[]>{
    return this.http.get<Spending[]>(`${this.baseUrl}spendings`);
  }

  createSpending(spending : Spending): Observable<any>{
    return this.http.post(`${this.baseUrl}spendings` , spending);
  }

  deleteSpending(id: number): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.delete(`${this.baseUrl}spendings/${id}`);
  }

  getSpendingsByDate(startDate: string, endDate: string): Observable<Spending[]> {
    const formattedStartDate = formatDate(startDate, 'yyyy-MMM-dd', 'tr-TR');
    const formattedEndDate = formatDate(endDate, 'yyyy-MMM-dd', 'tr-TR');
    const apiUrl = `${this.baseUrl}spendings?startDate=${formattedStartDate}&endDate=${formattedEndDate}`;
  
    return this.http.get<Spending[]>(apiUrl);
  }

  getSpendingsByMonth(month: string): Observable<Spending[]> {
    const formattedMonth = month.toLowerCase(); // Ay adını küçük harfe dönüştürün
    return this.http.get<Spending[]>(`${this.baseUrl}spendings/${formattedMonth}`);
  }
  
}
```

`MonthlySpendingComponent`

```
export class MonthlySpendingComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  months: string[] = ['Ocak', 'Şubat', 'Mart', 'Nisan', 'Mayıs', 'Haziran', 'Temmuz', 'Ağustos', 'Eylül', 'Ekim', 'Kasım', 'Aralık'];
  spendingsByMonth: Map<string, Spending[]> = new Map<string, Spending[]>();
  chartData: any[] = [];

  constructor(private spendingService: SpendingService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getAllSpendingsByMonths();
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.showChart();
  }

  getAllSpendingsByMonths(): void {
    this.spendingService.getAllSpendings().subscribe(spendings => {
      this.months.forEach(month => {
        const filteredSpendings = spendings.filter(spending => {
          const spendingMonth = spending.date ? new Date(spending.date).getMonth() : -1;
          return spendingMonth === this.months.indexOf(month);
        });
        this.spendingsByMonth.set(month, filteredSpendings);
      });
      this.updateChartData();
    });
  }
  
  
  getMonthInEnglish(month: string): string {
    const monthsInEnglish = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];
    const monthIndex = this.months.indexOf(month);
    return monthsInEnglish[monthIndex];
  }
  
  updateChartData(): void {
    this.chartData = [];
  
    this.months.forEach(month => {
      const spendings = this.spendingsByMonth.get(month);
      const totalAmount = spendings ? spendings.reduce((sum, spending) => sum + spending.price, 0) : 0;
  
      this.chartData.push({
        month: month,
        amount: totalAmount
      });
    });
  
    this.showChart();
  }

  showChart(): void {
    const ctx = document.getElementById('spendingChart') as HTMLCanvasElement;
    const labels = this.chartData.map(data => this.getMonthInEnglish(data.month)); // Ay adını İngilizce olarak alın
    const data = this.chartData.map(data => data.amount);
  
    // Önceki grafik nesnesini yok et
    const existingChart = Chart.getChart(ctx);
    if (existingChart) {
      existingChart.destroy();
    }
  
    new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'bar',
      data: {
        labels: labels, // Ay adlarını kullanın
        datasets: [{
          label: 'Total Spending',
          data: data,
          backgroundColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.5)',
          borderColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
          borderWidth: 1
        }]
      },
      options: {
        scales: {
          y: {
            beginAtZero: true
          }
        }
      }
    });
  }
  

}
```

`I added this method to Angular and created a chart, but only the expenses of March and May are coming, because the first 3 letters of March and May in Turkish and the first 3 letters in English are the same, but other months since there is no similarity to the Turkish and English month name in other months, these expenses do not appear on the chart, unfortunately, it is probably simple. There is a method but I couldn't find it, please help`